# What does mongoose findByIdAndUpdate return if it fails to update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

If `findByIdAndUpdate` fails to update, will it return the original document as is?

Or will it return nothing, `null`, `undefined`, or....?

In this example let's assume there's 1000 clients each with their own unique client._id

```
let promises = []

clients.forEach((clientId) => {
        promises.push(
          this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(
            clientId,
            {
              'some_property': 'new_value',
            },
            { new: true },
          ),
        );
      });
    });

return Promise.all(promises);
```

Let's say 100 fail to update, will I be returned 1000 documents, 900 updated and 100 not updated?
OR will I just be returned the 900 that have been updated?

Comment: `findByIdAndUpdate` takes in the `_id` as filter. This `_id` will always be unique so I dont understand how will this update 1000 docs anyway?

Comment: @ArbazSiddiqui I'll update it so it reflects better, but it's assumed that the 1000 clients each have their own unique Id.